# bool column in where clause - linq/c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
 Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> employeeWhere = R => true;
 employeeWhere = R => R.PositionCode == "M";
 employeeWhere = R => R.IsActive; //want only ones which are true
```

Will the above build me a query of this :

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE POSITIONCODE = "M" && IsActive = 1
```

This is what I want to return

```
 var result = _db.Employees
              .Where(employeeWhere)
              .Select(p => new { p.EmployeeID, p.FName, p.MName, p.LName })
              .AsEnumerable()
              .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.EmployeeID, kvp => kvp.FName + " " + kvp.MName + " " + kvp.LName);

        return new SelectList(result, "Key", "Value");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above does not build the SQL query you posted, if that's what you're asking.

Unless I'm mistaken, you overwrite the value of employeeWhere twice. I think you need:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> employeeWhere = R => R.PositionCode == "M" && R.IsActive;
```

If you had input parameters (say *bool myBoolParam* and *decimal myDecimalParam*) to whatever method this is in, you could do something like this:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> employeeWhere =
    (R => R.PositionCode == "M" && R.IsActive && myBoolParam && R.Salary > myDecmialParam);
```

Comment: I see your point. Begs me to ask this ? If I had to check if input params had values, how would i build the where clause dynamically?

Comment: Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> is a type that holds a Lambda function, which is just regular code. You can put anything you want in there, as long as it takes an Employee as a parameter and returns a boolean value. I'll put an example above.

Comment: Thanks Josh. IF i have to do this:
1.Check if PositionCode is enetered, if Y then add expression
2.check if salary value is entered, if Y then add to expression

is there a way to keep appending based on the conditions more like Dictionary.Add..ie. Expression.Add?

Comment: I think you're starting to get into a second, complicated question here. :) Please post this more verbosely in another question and put the link here, and I'll hit it, if you don't mind :)

Comment: Josh. Marking your answer as the one and starting new question

Comment: For anyone who is following the thread and is interested, the new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266742/append-to-an-expression-linq-c

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
var query = from e in _db.Employees
            where e.PositionCode == "M" && e.IsActive
            select new { e.EmployeeID, 
                Value = e.FName + " " + e.MName + " " + e.LName                 
            };

return new SelectList(query.ToDictionary(x => x.EmployeeID, "Key", "Value");
```