# Add additional WHERE clause to existing Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which accepts a linq query:

```
 public IEnumerable<User> GetAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<UserDTO, bool>> query)
 {
     return GetAllDTO(query);
 }
```

What I would like to be able to do is append an additional WHERE clause to this existing query so it looks something like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<User> GetAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<UserDTO, bool>> query)
 {
    return GetAllDTO(query).Where(x => x.Organisation == "something")
 }
```

But this will load ALL the records and that match the query and THEN apply the where clause. I want to add the where clause to the original query so that only the records matching both are returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266742/how-to-append-to-an-expression

Comment: Don't modify the result of `GetAllDTO(...)`. Modify the `query` before you call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example modifies the query before executing it:

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetAll(Expression<Func<int, bool>> currentQuery)
{
     Expression left = currentQuery.Body;
     BinaryExpression right = Expression.GreaterThan(
         currentQuery.Parameters[0], Expression.Constant(0));
     BinaryExpression combined = Expression.AndAlso(left, right);
     Expression<Func<int, bool>> final = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
         combined, currentQuery.Parameters[0]);
     return GetAllInt(final);
}
```

If `currentQuery` starts as `x => x != 5`, the function above will return `x => (x != 5) && (x > 0)`.

Here's the remaining example code:

```
private static readonly List<int> TheList = 
    new List<int> { 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5 };

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> initialQuery = x => x != 5;
    IEnumerable<int> result = GetAll(initialQuery);
    foreach (int i in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the `GetAllInt` method:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetAllInt(Expression<Func<int, bool>> query)
{
    return TheList.Where(query.Compile());
}
```

This prints out:

```
1
2
3
4
```

This may not fit your situation exactly but should at least give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<UserDTO, bool>> query)
{
  var prefix = query.Compile();
  query = c => prefix(c) && c.Organisation == organisationID;
}
```