# Filtering with Expression<Func<TModel>> using view model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, filtering

I have a method for paginating a table in a database. Paginating part is not important, so the only focus is filtering part.

Since Where method from Entity Framework Core asks for `Expression<Func<T>>` as a parameter, where `T` is an actual model and I have action in controller which asks for a valid view model, how can I use that view model to generate `Expression<Func<T>>` from that view model?

I want to be able to filter table based on filled parameters in the view model.

Comment: Can you add more details to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Well you basically need the `Expression<Func<YourModel, bool>>`. You build a filter to pass to EF.  The below info is more than enough to get you started.

So imagine you have a class like the below. This can be any class not just a ViewModel.

```
public class Person
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

The expression would look sth like this.

```
Expression<Func<Person,bool>> predicate = p => p.Name == "Some name";
db.People.Where(predicate); // How you would use it in a db context
```

You can also view this link that uses *LinqKit*.You do not have to use LinqKit but has some nice examples http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

> I want to be able to filter table based on filled parameters in the view model.

Since you want the above you can append to your `predicate` and just pass it to your `Where,Any,Count...` as one. 
You can see a lot of techniques to how to append to your filter here:
[How to Append to an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266742/how-to-append-to-an-expression)

My favorite way of appending is using linqkit predicate builder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx 
In the [above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266742/how-to-append-to-an-expression) many techniques are showcased including the predicate builder.